# Why are the Galois conjugates of a sum of roots of unity also sums of roots of unity?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I'm trying to solve [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1511344/average-of-sum-of-unit-roots-is-an-algebraic-integer), which is to prove that, if the average of some (not necessarily distinct) roots of unity is an algebraic integer, it is either a root of unity or $0$. Say the roots of unity in question are $\varepsilon_1, \varepsilon_2,\dots,\varepsilon_n$. In the various solutions I've seen, it is always mentioned that the Galois conjugates of $\varepsilon_1+\varepsilon_2+\cdots+\varepsilon_n$ must be a sum of roots of unity, but I've never seen this explained. I understand that the conjugates of roots of unity are roots of unity, but conjugates aren't additive, so why should it be the case that the conjugates of a sum of roots of unity is also a sum of roots of unity?

Comment: taking conjugates is additive, field automorphisms respect addition

Comment: @TokenToucan Oh, right. Thank you

Comment: The argument TokenToucan suggests requires a slightly nontrivial fact about Galois theory: you need to know that every element of the Galois group of a Galois extension $K/\mathbb{Q}$ extends to an element of the Galois group of any Galois extension containing $K$. (Once you know this it follows that "the Galois conjugates of $\alpha$" is well-defined, in the sense that it's independent of which Galois extension you compute the Galois conjugates in.)